# How can i disable a button that work in iphone in an ipad since the ipads dosent have the features

Tags: swift

How can i disable a button that work in iphone in an ipad since the ipads dosent have the features so i wish i cloud disable the bottom for ipad my code is programmaticlly thanks

```swift
self.toggleBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
self.toggleBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.toggleBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "torch"), for: .normal)
self.toggleBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(BtnPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.toggleBtn.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.6)
view.addSubview(self.toggleBtn)
```

Comment: It's very simple to disable a button. What are you having trouble with exactly? BTW - why disable the button? If it can't be used at all on a given device, you shouldn't show it at all. Otherwise the user will wonder what to do to get it enabled.

Comment: I don't know the exact requirement, but if you want to disable user interaction of button just add this line of code `self.toggleBtn. isUserInteractionEnabled = false` or `self.toggleBtn.isEnabled = false`

Comment: @channu Using `isEnabled` is better because to changes the look of the button.

Comment: @rmaddy exactly that is the Recommended approach

Comment: i wish to disable it since the iPads dosent have a flashlight but for iPhone i do wanted it to be available for use

Comment: For devices that don't have a torch/flashlight, don't show the button at all.

Comment: yea ik but my code is programmaticlly and idk how to do it

Comment: You don't know how to not add a button or you don't know how to check if the device supports a torch/flashlight? Your question is unclear. Please [edit] your question with what you specifically need help with. Certainly you must have reviewed the documentation for this.

Comment: I want to disable the bottom from the iPad since it dosent have a function I want it disabled but in the iPhone I wanted it enabled